# BSP Build Configurations in Xilinx SDK

Tags: eclipse, sdk, xilinx

In Xilinx SDK (an Eclipse-based IDE), when I right-click on a BSP project, the Build Configurations menu items are greyed out.

In particular, I want BSP build configuration to set USE_AMP flag (or not).  I've been creating two separate BSP projects, one with USE_AMP=1 and one without, and switching my application between the BSPs.  I thought it would be nicer to have one BSP project with different build configurations, but Xilinx SDK is not allowing build configuration options for BSP projects.  Regular application projects are able to have build configurations.

Does Xilinx SDK support build configurations for BSP projects?